# Unable to get haxe-pixi.js to work - I get a blank white screen

Tags: javascript, haxe, extern, flashdevelop, pixi.js

***EDIT:
OK! Got it working. The missing library in the html was the trick. The pixi.min.js file was missing from the haxelib directory, not sure if that's normal.

Another more complex question: what's the possibility of including pixijs as a renderer/html5 backend in openfl/haxeflixel?

I tried to include haxe-pixi in openfl/flixel projects targetting html5 but
the same error comes back despite including pixijs in the .html file and project.xml files

---

i am unable to get haxe javascript +
[Pixi.js library](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-haxe) to work in flashdevelop.

I have installed haxe, used haxelib to dl pixijs library, included pixijs in my project properties... But when i run the project in html, a blank white screen appears.

But i could still use typical javascriipt stuff without the pixi library eg buttons, helloworld

Coming from a flash background, im new to javascript and haxe...
Appreciate ur help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see any errors if you open up your web browser's developer console when you get that blank white screen?

Comment: Yes. PIXI was not found or smth. Im new to this , hopefully this information would help others like me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might have forgotten to include pixiJS in your html.

Comment: Sry could u elaborate on that? Which html file? Im a noob at this sry

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I couldn't write that string here, because it contains html tags

string for index.html is: [script src="pixi.min.js"][/script] and you need to change "[" to "<" and "]" to ">"

place this string between tags  body and /body